# “No such interface supported” utilizando Visual Studio 2015 Diagnostic Tools

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015

Estoy tratando de usar **Visual Studio 2015 Diagnostic Tools** pero cuando abro la ventana aparece este mensaje:

```
The diagnostic tools failed unexpectedly.
```

[image]

Luego reviso la *output window* y configuro el output para  ***Diagnostics Hub*** allí me arroja

```
No such interface supported
No such interface supported
```

- Actualmente estoy corriendo una aplicación .NET de consola. Consumiendo un API REST hosteada en Azure
- Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 1 14.0.24720.00

¿A qué se puede deber el error?, ¿cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: hace poco actualizaste una versión de Windows 10 ya teniendo instalado Visual Studio?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Según parece es un problema relacionado con alguna actualización de Windows, el proceso de actualización no tiene en cuenta o modifica de manera errónea unos archivos que interfieren con el funcionamiento de la ventana Herramientas de diagnóstico.

La solución que hay *-aunque se supone que en alguna versión posterior de Visual Studio esto seria solucionado-* es borrar dichos archivos siguiendos estas instrucciones.

1. Cierre Visual Studio.
2. Abra con permisos de administrador la consola (**cmd**)
3. Escriba los siguientes comandos:

```bash
cd %systemroot%\system32     

takeown /f DiagnosticsHub.*    

icacls DiagnosticsHub.* /grant %username%:F

del /q DiagnosticsHub.*
```

Ahora lo recomendado sería reiniciar VS.

Puedes leer mas al respecto [**aquí**](https://web.archive.org/web/20160201155518/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/07/24/no-such-interface-supported-in-visual-studio-2015-on-windows-10.aspx).

Comment: resuelto! incluso había reinstalado VS 2015 sin éxito.